# Как сделать курсор в EditText немигающим?

Tags: java, android

В приложении армянская клавиатура можно набрать армянские буквы в `EditText` через кнопки, в то же время активна и системная клавиатура, чтобы можно было набрать другие буквы тоже. При входе системная клавиатура неактивна и появляется только после нажатия на `EditText`. Нужно также сделать курсор видимым, чтобы знать его положение.

```
textArea.setActivated(true);
textArea.setPressed(true);
```

Это EditText

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textArea"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
android:background="#DDDDDD"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="5"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp" />
```

Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопки, курсор, так как мигает, до того, как софт клавиатура неактивна, мигает только после нажатия на кнопку и в половине случаев не отображается. Только после того, как софт клавиатура включается, курсор начинает мигать непрерывно. Как отключить его мигание, когда клавиатура еще не включена? То есть, как сделать, чтобы курсор был видимим и не мигал?

Comment: просто отключить или сделать чтоб не мигал? 
первый варинат 1 строчкой, 2 довольно сложно делать. Или чтоб он вырубался, по тапу на кнопку

Comment: Нужно, чтобы курсор был видимим и не мигал.

Comment: Да, добавьте это в вопрос, это очень разные вещи, хоть и кажется почти одинаковым